# How do I properly pass an url with get variables as a get variable?

Tags: php, get, mysql-real-escape-string, html-escape-characters

So, I have a link like this...

`http://my-affiliate.com?pr=9&user=274934&ad_id=12598`

And I am trying to pass it through a link with get variables, such as...

`http://my-website.com/ad-tracking.php?userID=1&link=http://my-affiliate.com?pr=9&user=274934&ad_id=12598`

But when I do that, it recognizes the affiliate's get variables as my own. So, the link get variable turns out to be `http://my-affiliate.com?pr=9`.

How can I fix this? I appreciate it. Thank You.

Comment: `urlencode()` function to the rescue.

Comment: oh, thank goodness. I was looking for every escape function I can find. That's one that was not findable lol. Guess I was searching wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Tested and works perfect. Thanks.